# Is a CMS portal a web server?

Tags: content-management-system, webserver

I know it's a dumb question but a colleague of mine schooled me saying that a CMS is a web server, and now I'm confused.

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No A CMS is not a web server.

A CMS system has to be inside a web server if it were meant to perform.

Comment: we have a portal(CMS) he keeps saying that it is a web server.

Comment: Do you have more details of the CMS. I could clarify my point further. A good example of a popular web server is Apache. It receives http requests and then processes the requests where as a CMS can only be alive if its under a web server such as Wordpress, Joomla or any CMS. CMS works in a different way. When a page in a CMS is requested by the user it relies on its database to retrieve content.